# php big upload via ftp

Tags: php, ftp

i have to trasfer file via ftp with php. The files are big (also over 500MB).
So i think use php with ftp.

```
<?php
// connect and login to FTP server
 $ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

$file = "localfile.txt";

// upload file
if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, "serverfile.txt", $file, FTP_ASCII))
  {
  echo "Successfully uploaded $file.";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error uploading $file.";
  }

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
?>
```

I have to know if the timeout is considered also in ftp trasfer.
If i trasfer the file via php page like upload.php with the code write, i have the execution time limit setting on the web server ?

Answer (score 1):

You must take too many considerations before doing this operation, as mentioned below the first thing you need to check if your FTP server allows 500MB for uploads, the second thing you must set some PHP directives like post_max_size and max_upload_size, I suggest to use an FTP library to make it easier to do that, this a great one [php-ftp-client](https://github.com/lazzard/php-ftp-client) that I've build.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the feature on server side, which allows resuming file uploads.

From php you might be able to call the ftp with command_line options using functions like system(), or exec().

And, yes, in php there are limits: max_upload_size, max_execution_time, max_post_size and etc.
You will have to split the whole process into steps, with reloading of the page - if needed.

Comment: So you say with php and Ajax i can resolve this ? For example with XMLHttpRequest object...

Comment: You misunderstood me. What I told you about is using command line syntax with php, meaning calling ftp with something like "system('call ftp upload via unix command line')" - which will make sure your file will be uploaded. You will need to know your local ftp program and how to call it via command line. http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php You can avoid php time limits with setting them to 0 and also using special abort on php side - the script launched will continue to execute even past the time limit then. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php